# $\|D\|=\max |D_{ii}|$ for any $n \times n$ diagonal matrix $D$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that $D=(D_{i,j})$ is an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix. Is it true for any natural norm $\|\cdot\|$ that $\|D\|=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} |D_{ii}|$?

I know that this is true for the $2$-norm, but I do not think this is true in general. Does anyone know a counterexample?

Comment: If the typographical difference $\vphantom{\dfrac11}$ between $||D||$ and $\|D\|$ is not conspicuous to you, look at the difference between $||D|| ||E||$ and $\|D\|\|E\|$ and you see why the latter form is standard. 
$\phantom{++}$ The former is coded as ||D|| ||E|| and the latter as \|D\|\|E\|. I edited $\vphantom{\dfrac11}$the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy For those whitespace characters: is there a difference between `\phantom{++}` and `\qquad` (just curious)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : The former is a bit longer. My purpose was actually to make sure that the code wasn't interrupted by a line break, and I thought at first that \phantom{+} would be enough for that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ah, interesting.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *natural norm* means a matrix norm induced by a vector norm, then it is generally not true.

For any induced matrix norm and a diagonal $D$, we have
$$
\|D\|=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Dx\|}{\|x\|}\geq\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{\|De_i\|}{\|e_i\|}=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|D_{ii}|
$$
obtained by picking $x$ to be columns of the identity matrix.
So the maximum of $|D_{ii}|$ is at least a lower bound on $\|D\|$.

There are cases, where the inequality becomes an equality. This is true for any matrix $p$-norm with $1\leq p\leq \infty$.

In order to construct a counterexample, consider a vector norm
$$
\|x\|_M:=\|Mx\|_\infty
$$
with a nonsingular matrix $M$.
The induced matrix norm is related to the $\infty$-norm by
$$
\|D\|_M=\|MDM^{-1}\|_\infty.
$$
For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and with
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix},
\quad
M=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix},
$$
we get
$$
\|D\|_M=3> 2=\max_{1\leq i\leq2}|D_{ii}|.
$$

Comment: That seems to be the correct interpretation of [natural norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNorm.html).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Does it suffice to just multiply by $M$ on the left, rather than by $M$ on the left and its inverse on the right?

Comment: @Sarah Nope: if a matrix norm is defined as $\|x\|_M=\|Mx\|$, then for the induced matrix norm we have $\|A\|_M=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_M}{\|x\|_M}
=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|MAx\|}{\|Mx\|}
=\max_{y\neq 0}\frac{\|MAM^{-1}y\|}{\|y\|}
=\|MAM^{-1}\|$.